# Can't calculate value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, largenumber

I am trying to calculate value of this expression:

```
int((1770246808796936040 * 1103515245 + 12345 / 65536) % 32768)
```

And it gives `0`. Without `int` cast, it is `0` too.

Does anyone know why it so? Are these numbers too big for Python? Is any way to handle the issue? Appreciate any help.

Comment: I guess the issue is resolved, mark any of the answers as accepted to close it.

Comment: What do you think the answer should be, and why? It looks like one step of an [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), in particular see the 4th line of [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use), but you have misunderstood the order of operations and incorrectly parenthesized it. In python a correct expression would be `((1770246808796936040 * 1103515245 + 12345) // 65536) % 32768`

Answer (score 2):

The number calculated from the expression

```
1770246808796936040 * 1103515245 + 12345 / 65536
```

is divisible by 32768, that's why you get 0.

To give you an idea of Python's capacity to handle huge numbers, you can see this:

```
>>> 10**1000
```

> 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 2):

The `%` operator gives the remainder of a division. Since

> (1770246808796936040 * 1103515245 + 12345 / 65536)

is divisible by 32768, the result is 0.
To obtain the quotient, you should use the operator `/` instead of `%`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the numbers' combination is such that the result is 0. Increase or decrease any number by even 1 and you will see that it is not 0. For example see below. I changed 32768 to 32769.

```py
print(int((1770246808796936040 * 1103515245 + 12345 / 65536) % 32769))
```

It gives.

```py
21725
```